NX @nx/next to create host and remote app where both appplications are Next based
I am currently working on a project where I would like to create a mono-repo with multiple next applications with  host and remote module-federation.
Need help on how to have host and remote applications to be a next app using NX.
I am following the steps described in https://nx.dev/nx-api/next
https://nx.dev/recipes/module-federation/create-a-host
I am not able to find a solution on how to use module federation with Next
